# Tobit model for continuous zero inflated data?

Tags: continuous-data, zero-inflation, tobit-regression

I would like advice on how to apply an appropriate linear model to my data.

I have several continuous independent variables, and a dependant variable with continuous distance measurements. 
This dependant variable is strongly right-skewed and is inflated at zero (somewhere around 40-50% of data points have value 0).
When considering all the data points (including ones with distance = 0) i believe tha data most closely follow a gamma distribution.
When droping "zero observations" the best fitting distributions are gamma or weibull.

I thought Tobit model (or possibly some other model that applies right-censoring at zero) would be appropriate. So i attempted to apply a tobit model in R using iether the "censreg"-function from package "Censreg", or the "tobit"-function from package "EMA". But i cannot get this to work.

Is Tobit model the right choise for me, or is there another model i should use instead?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a difference between a censoring process and a zero-inflation process. Which is likely closest to your data-generating model?